# aapt error parsing xml:unbound prefix

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and am trying to implement a simple animation. I looked at the android API for examples and found one. I created an animator file and created the following animation xml by copying from the API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueTo="400"
        android:valueType="intType"
   <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueTo="300"
        android:valueType="intType"
</set>
   <objectAnimator
        android:propertyName="Alpha"
        android:duration="500"
        android:valueTo="1f"

It says:
```

Not well formed invalid token

aapt error parsing xml:unbound prefix

Comment: Is that your entire XML? Unbound prefix means you are missing a namespace in your XML.

Comment: That is my entire xml in the 'animator' file.

Comment: I have a fully functional UI layout file though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code snippet, you are missing the namespace for the "android" prefix; hence, the "unbound prefix" error.

For clarity, make sure you include the doc-type at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Here is the namespace(add this to **your** set tag):

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

For example, please see and utilize this example from Google using the `namespace`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@[package:]anim/interpolator_resource"
    android:shareInterpolator=["true" | "false"] >
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="float"
        android:toAlpha="float" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="float"
        android:toXScale="float"
        android:fromYScale="float"
        android:toYScale="float"
        android:pivotX="float"
        android:pivotY="float" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="float"
        android:toXDelta="float"
        android:fromYDelta="float"
        android:toYDelta="float" />
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="float"
        android:toDegrees="float"
        android:pivotX="float"
        android:pivotY="float" />
    <set>
        ...
    </set>
</set>
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Comment: So, I include a the Linear Layout in my animation xml too? I am a beginner in android so this helps me out a lot.

Comment: @DustinJackson No. Please see my updated example taken straight from the Android docs. I have seen your error before.

Comment: Thanks. I was using information from the following link:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: @DustinJackson Does it work for you now? Yes, I have seen that link. Google "assumes" you will use the correct namespace.

Comment: It said: error parsing invalid animation. I am beginning to think It might be my software. I use the AIDE app as I don't have direct access to a PC so I developed straight to my phone.

Comment: Ah, you currently can only develop on your phone?

Comment: Yes. I have used the eclipse compatible AIDE app to develop to my phone and tablet. Phone is 4.0 and tab is 4.4. I used it to learn java and then some android basics a couple months ago.

Comment: @DustinJackson All I know is that you should most likely use Android Studio like Google wants you to on an actual computer. I can't debug the AIDE developer tools. It may be a totally different issue with AIDE's aapt.

Comment: I am getting a laptop this Christmas and plan on using Android Studio. I just wanted to start earlier than Christmas. Anyway, thanks for the help.